# How to get access token for text to speech for azure cognitive services in java

Tags: spring, text-to-speech

This is c# code for getting access token but I want java equivalent of this code can anyone help me. I want to get access token for azure cognitive services. How to put in HttpClient for java version.

```
  public class Authentication
   {
public static readonly string FetchTokenUri =
    "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken";
private string subscriptionKey;
private string token;

public Authentication(string subscriptionKey)
{
    this.subscriptionKey = subscriptionKey;
    this.token = FetchTokenAsync(FetchTokenUri, subscriptionKey).Result;
}

public string GetAccessToken()
{
    return this.token;
}

private async Task<string> FetchTokenAsync(string fetchUri, string subscriptionKey)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", subscriptionKey);
        UriBuilder uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(fetchUri);

        var result = await client.PostAsync(uriBuilder.Uri.AbsoluteUri, null);
        Console.WriteLine("Token Uri: {0}", uriBuilder.Uri.AbsoluteUri);
        return await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: That is not really how this works. Nobody is just going to write your code for you. We all have busy lives as well. You need to at least try to write it yourself, and if it doesnt work, that is when you come to us and we will try to help you to understand why and what to change.

Comment: Yeah, I have written and it is working successfully now.